# Using super in a subclass member in Python

Tags: python, class, subclass, super

Consider the following code:

```
>>> class A:
...    k = 1
...
>>> class B(A):
...     k = super(B, cls).k
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 2, in B1
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

Why is this causing the error and what is the best way to get around it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `super()` in a class definition body in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super()` can only be used in a *method*, not in the class definition. It needs access to the class MRO, which is not yet known when the `B` class body is being built.

Even better, `B` isn't bound yet when the class is being defined! That doesn't happen until after the class body has been executed; you first need a class body before you can create a class object.

Just don't override `k`:

```
class A:
    k = 1

class B(A):
    pass
```

and `B.k` is inherited from `A`.

or reference it directly; you know exactly what base classes you have, when defining a class, after all:

```
class A:
    k = 1

class B(A):
    k = A.k
```